# SSIS Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, ssis, oracle11g

I have 191 table and view creation scripts for Oracle DB. I thought it will be more efficient to use the Execute SQL task in SSIS. I set up my Execute SQL task and Foreach loop container. I have connection to my Oracle DB 11g but i keep getting error whn I run the task.

```
Error: 0xC002F210 at Execute SQL Task, Execute SQL Task: Executing the query "--------------------------------------------------..." failed with the following error: "ORA-00911: invalid character". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
Task failed: Execute SQL Task
```

When I create a simple insert query and save to a .sql, the row gets inserted to the db so I know there's no issue with my connection to the DB.

One of my sql files looks like that.

```
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table ACCOUNT
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "DBSCHEMA"."ACCOUNT" 
   (    "MNT_IN_BO" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "ACCT_KEY" CHAR(34 BYTE), 
    "BRCH_MNM" CHAR(8 BYTE), 
    "CUS_SBB" CHAR(8 BYTE), 
    "CUS_MNM" CHAR(20 BYTE), 
    "ACC_TYPE" CHAR(10 BYTE), 
    "ACC_SEQNO" NUMBER, 
    "CATEGORY" CHAR(20 BYTE), 
    "CURRENCY" CHAR(3 BYTE), 
    "OTHER_CCY" CHAR(3 BYTE), 
    "CONTINGENT" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "INTRNAL" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "SHORTNAME" CHAR(15 BYTE), 
    "BO_ACCTNO" CHAR(34 BYTE), 
    "EXT_ACCTNO" CHAR(34 BYTE), 
    "IBAN" CHAR(34 BYTE), 
    "COUNTRY" CHAR(2 BYTE), 
    "DATEOPENED" DATE, 
    "DATECLOSED" DATE, 
    "DATEMAINT" DATE, 
    "DATE_DWNL" DATE, 
    "DESCR1" CHAR(35 BYTE), 
    "DESCR2" CHAR(35 BYTE), 
    "TYPEFLAG" NUMBER, 
    "TSTAMP" NUMBER
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 16384 NEXT 8724480 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
```

When I run the creation script against the Db directly, the table is created.
What could be the issue? How do I get the task to ignore errors and move to the next file whilst keeping a record of which files had errors.

[image: Execute task]

Comment: Are you using the Oracle OLE DB driver or the Microsoft one?

Comment: I am using the Oracle OLE DB driver.

Comment: What was the resolution of this?